# How to create an array of HTML colors with a certain gradient distribution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, color-codes

JavaScript. I have an array of numbers 
`var values = [1,20,12,6,9];`

I need to create a new array of the same size such that:

1. the element corresponding to the maximum element in the first
   array is ALWAYS `"#3E296B"`
2. the element corresponding to the
   minimum element of the first array is ALWAYS `"#FFFFFF"`.
3. other elements should get gradient colors of `"#3E296B"` segueing into `"#FFFFFF"` proportionately to their values

i.e. my new array should be approximately like: `var colors = [white, blue, less_blue, less_less_blue, less_blue]` (I wrote in words to simplify)

Comment: @Rick Viscomi I tried to concatenate the RGB values. I got stuck with the letters, I mean it is not Hexadecimal, so I do not know how to specify that A is greater than 9 etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a library that solves this exact problem:

https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS

So after including it you would do something like:

```
var rainbow = new Rainbow();
rainbow.setSpectrum('#ffffff', '#3E296B');
rainbow.setNumberRange(1, 20); 
rainbow.colourAt(number); // based on the numbers from your array, this would return the color you want
```

Comment: Six years later, still an awesome lib